# Does anybody know how to decode plot data points as extracted from a Python bokeh-generated html file?

Tags: python, numpy, bokeh

Reading the html source I see that data arrays are formatted like:

```
              'x' => 
              array (
                '__ndarray__' => 'A loooooong string',
                'dtype' => 'float64',
                'shape' => 
                array (
                  0 => 3053,
                ),
```

I have tried casting octets of chars into a 64 bit numpy float, attempting different endiannesses, without success. I haven't tried reversing the order of characters in the string, but I would be surprised if it helps.

Comment: You should provide the looong string, cause that's the data. Encode an array like `np.arange(6.0).reshape(2, 3)` for an mcve

Answer (score 2):

This is the function that you need: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/2.0.0/bokehjs/src/lib/core/util/serialization.ts#L126

I can't paste the code here since there are different dependencies, and gathering them all in a single code block requires quite some effort.

Comment: What language is that written in?

Comment: @MadPhysicist TypeScript, it compiles to JavaScript.